# PHP Arrays, Serialization and Unserialization

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have a problem. I have a website with people and different transactions they make to and from a fake online bank. I want to be able to store an array of each person's transactions on my mysql database. I want each transaction to be defined as an associative array with a timestamp and the sql query that represents their transaction with the "bank".

Then I want those, after being serialized, to be the values of a transactions array that holds all of their transactions. Then I want to serialize that and store it in the database so that later I can add a transaction by unserializing it and appending a serialized array of another transaction to it. So far this code below works except that it just overwrites the one transaction and doesn't append a new one. I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

```
function modify_transactions($row, $sql)
{
 $sql=mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
 if(isset($row["TRANSACTIONS"]))
 {
  $transactions = unserialize($row["TRANSACTIONS"]);
 }
 else
 {
  $transactions = array();
 }
 $transaction_array = array("timestamp"=>time(),"query"=>$sql);
 $transaction_data  = serialize($transaction_array);
 $transactions[] = $transaction_data;
 $transactions_upload = serialize($transactions);
 $name = $row["NAME"];
 $query = "UPDATE band.students SET TRANSACTIONS = '$transactions_upload' WHERE students.NAME = '$name'";
 mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: If you `var_dump($row)`, are you actually seeing `$row['TRANSACTIONS']` having a string value?

Comment: yes I do it displays the serialized form of the latest transaction inside of transactions

Comment: Similar to: [Storing arrays in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031254/storing-arrays-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I'd rather go for a new table where every entry would represent a transaction and that had a foreign key `student_id`.

That'd be much, much, much cleaner and more flexible and scalable (i.e. what if you want to show the last 3 transactions of user X? What if a user had several million transactions?).

Answer (score 1):

**First, you don't need to serialize each array, then serialize again.**  Serialize is recursive:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        '1',
        array()
    ),
    array(
        '2',
        array()
    )
);

$serialized = serialize($array);

$unserialized = unserialize($serialized);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($unserialized);
echo "</pre>";
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

So just serialize right before inserting into the database.

**Second, you should change your database structure.**  Like vzwick mentioned, create a new table with a foreign key of the student.  That way each entry represents a transaction.

Also, why are you storing the actual SQL query?  That doesn't make any sense to me. Why don't you actually make a fake transaction?