# Can we store List type of data to MYSQL database table?

Tags: mysql

I need to store some data of list type into a MYSQL database.Is it possible to store it in MYSQL,if yes then what should be the data type of the field that will hold this  data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes we can insert.check the below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371639/how-to-store-arrays-in-mysql

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the list and why you want to store it in a relational database?

Comment: And this list type is data type in which language exactly?

Answer (score 13):

## No, no, no, no, no! Never store multiple values in a single column!

Seperate the values and store each of them in another record.

For instance if you have users and want to store a list of the roles each user has then you can do it like this

```
users table
-----------
id
name
...


roles table
-----------
id
name


user_roles table
----------------
user_id
role_id
```

Comment: Never say never (except now, LOL). There are cases when due to very specific reasons a JSON or a comma-separated value is stored. Off course, the rule you have described is the general rule, but there are some valid exceptions which are implied by specific business logic.

Comment: There are cases that normalizing a table is bad. Not all value should be normalize.

Comment: @GTHell: When, for instance??

Comment: @juergend when storing list of JSON that contain data that would kill MySql read performance if normalize. For example, the dictionary list of `plate_num: confidence` with 200 entry each for 3 set would equal 600 data. Tell me you don't want to store that in separate table. A 10000 transactions probably would generate 6000000 data. I know it's big data and should handle with the right database but not all have the fortune to use nosql.

Comment: @juergend Can you explain `why` multiple values shouldn't be stored in a single column? I get the solution but the problem doesn't seem to be properly fleshed out.

Comment: @piepi: One can write a whole book about that topic. Well, it is against the database normalization rules. Performance is really bad when a condition hits that column. Also updating is a nightmare ...

Comment: @juergend Can you point to an existing write up or a text on this topic?

Comment: Google *Database normalization*. For instance this article: https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html

Comment: It's an error to say that "normalization = good, denormalization = bad, therefore never store multiple values in a column." When dealing with large scale database systems, the locality of data is very important and denormalizing makes the database more scalable and more cacheable. While this is unlikely to be this user's scenario, you cannot make such a broad statement without at least adding that caveat.

Comment: @riwalk: What you describe is way beyond the question of the OP.

Comment: @juergend Ummm ... no, it's not. The schema you presented is excellent for small to medium sized datasets, but completely impractical for enormous datasets. The quality of this answer is entirely dependant on the scalability requirements of the data being stored.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `JSON` datatype.
`MySQL` provides `JSON` as `column` data type and provides some functions to work with `JSON` data.

Look at the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

**NOTE**: you must use 5.7+ version

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type that enables efficient access to data in JSON

Answer (score 3):

You can store it as a STRING, using VARCHAR data type column.

There is no specific data type in mysql designed to store specifically lists.

Other approach is to implode the list and store each member in a different row,  then when queried,  you can recreate the list, or array or JSON, in your preferred language.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SET datatype and this will store predefined data set in the mysql and not in the table and let you select value from the list up to 64 individual items

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table with two fields - the first being the list name and the second being the list items. This table would be like a join between the list and its items. Each list name would appear in the table as many times as there are items in the list. Each list item would appear in the table as many times as the number of lists it belongs to.

For example, say you want to store data about teams. Let's say that any person can be a member of more than one team. If Bob is on Team Blue and on Team Orange then there would be two records that include Bob - one where he's paired with Team Blue and one where he's paired with Team Orange. And if there are 10 people on Team Blue then there would be 10 records where Team Blue is mentioned - one for each member of Team Blue.

I think this solution does not follow the rules of normalization but it would be a practical, workable solution, wouldn't it?