# Replace Empty values with nulls in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with n number of columns and I want to replace empty strings in all these columns with nulls.

I tried using

```
val ReadDf = rawDF.na.replace("columnA", Map( "" -> null));
```

and

```
val ReadDf = rawDF.withColumn("columnA", if($"columnA"=="") lit(null) else $"columnA" );
```

Both of them didn't work.

Any leads would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There is many errors here and it's not just related to replacing an empty string with null but also the jdbc error and as a matter of fact, that second error can't be resolved with the current description and information because it cannot be reproduced. Please review your question as it is subject of being closed !

Comment: One thing I don't understand is, How is [this][1] relevant to the question I asked. It talks about an array of strings in MYSQL and my question was about replacing empty strings with nulls in the data frame. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Here it is. I haven't voted for this question to be closed as a duplicated but as I said in the comment earlier, you have 2 differents errors and the latest error message is related to the question mentioned by the voters.

Comment: @eliasah I was not referring to you. I am very sorry that I didn't address the persons. Let me see if I can edit the comment and add them.

Comment: I know you are not. That's not a problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6910411/user6910411, https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh, https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum
Can you guys explain how this question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371639/how-to-store-arrays-in-mysql? If this is a mistake, please remove it. Its quiet misleading

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed as a duplicate of an SQL question, but this has been reopened.

Answer (score 6):

Your first approach seams to fail due to a bug that prevents `replace` from being able to replace values with nulls, see [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14932?focusedCommentId=15723620&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15723620).

Your second approach fails because you're confusing driver-side Scala code for executor-side Dataframe instructions: your if-else expression would be evaluated **once** on the **driver** (and not per record); You'd want to replace it with a call to `when` function; Moreover, to compare a column's value you need to use the `===` operator, and not Scala's `==` which just compares the driver-side `Column` object:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

rawDF.withColumn("columnA", when($"columnA" === "", lit(null)).otherwise($"columnA"))
```