# Doctrine & Symfony - Get data from database with parameter on array column

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Good afternoon,

I try to find, from my database specific users with a role which is passed in parameter to the query. However, I have "null" result currently.

The users class is like this [example](https://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) from Symfony Documentation.

This is my CustomerRepository:

```
class CustomerRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Customer::class);
    }

    public function findByRole(string $role)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT c
             FROM App\Entity\Customer c
              WHERE c.roles IN (:role)'
        )
            ->setParameter(':role', $role)
            ->getResult()
        ;
    } 
}
```

I expect to return an array which contains one or several users who have the role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good evening,

Thx for your help.

To resolve this problem, I considered that a User have only one role in application, in this context, the solution is like this:

```
public function findByRole(string $role, int $isActive = 1): ?Customer
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
            'SELECT c
             FROM App\Entity\Cutomer c
             WHERE c.roles LIKE :role
             AND c.isActive = :isActive'
        )
        ->setParameters([
             ':role' => '%'.$role.'%',
             ':isActive' => $isActive,
        ])
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`c.roles` is a list that can contains multiple items (roles), so please can you reverse the where like this :

```
WHERE :role IN c.roles
```

PS: insure the case of `string $role` is upper (e.g "ROLE_ADMIN").

Answer (score 0):

First of all in the class from the example you have given does not have declared variable called roles, therefore you cannot write this

```
 ... WHERE c.roles IN (:role)'
```

So in your User class you should have something like this

```
private $roles;
```

> Also as it said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371639/how-to-store-arrays-in-mysql) you can have "multiple tables and JOIN them
>   in your queries."

So you would have 1 table for all your roles, one for the users and one called user_roles where you will store the roles for each user.
The next step I would approach is to search this new table for the user I want and then retrieve all rows containing the different roles in an array.

Also there are **other ways** - stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641889/how-to-use-php-serialize-and-unserialize). The method I recommend when storing arrays is to have a VARCHAR field (or TEXT) and then use (in your case) the [Symfony serializer component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object) to [serialize()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#serializing-an-object) the array when saving in the DB and to  [deserialize()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object)it when needed.

Comment: The Customer class contains an array type for $roles variable & in Doctrine, it is an array. No table has been added for this.

Comment: Ok.. So in the doctrine docs the array type is described as following - _Maps and converts array data based on PHP serialization._ and _This type will always be mapped to the database vendor's text type internally as there is no way of storing a PHP array_. So as I said before with few changes - doctrine saves a serialized array so you can use PHP deserialize to convert the data to array and then check if the value exists. Another way is using regex in where statement -  `'SELECT c
             FROM App\Entity\Customer c WHERE field REGEXP '.*"array_key";s:[0-9]+:".*array_value.*".*' `