# How to create a column of type array in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I have a table of 2 columns, **user_id** and **connection_type**. Both the fields are not unique. One single user id can appear many times and one single connection type can appear many times. How will I group all the connection types to one single user id?

`**Table I have:**

schema: user_id         -- INT
        connection_type -- STRING

**user_id**   **connection_type**
101       4g
102       3g
101       4g
101       2g
102       2g
101       4g
102       4g
101       4g
102       4g
101       4g

**Table I need from the above:**

**user_id**   **connection_type**
101       ['4g','4g','2g','4g','4g','4g']
102       ['3g','2g','4g','4g']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store arrays in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371639/how-to-store-arrays-in-mysql)