# how to create a SET data type with drizzle-orm

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, drizzle

What happens is that I am working with drizzle-orm, and I need a table which has to have a Set type field.

This is the one I should save: ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thur', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']

Can somebody help me.
I'm stuck with the mysql-core

drizzle-orm doesn't seem to have a type of data set for its models,

so I'm looking for a way to do it, perhaps using the custom data types that drizzle offers

Comment: Seems like a good use case for enum https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/column-types/mysql/#enumcolumn given it's very unlikely to change

Comment: but I needed to garden different data at the same time, enum only allows me to select one

Comment: Why do you need to store a set in a single column in your table? Tables are for storing sets, so your specific requirement would make more sense as a second table with 7 rows,  rather than storing 7 values in a single column.

Comment: in that case a custom column type https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/custom-types/ *may* work - but test if it breaks drizzle kit migrations before using.

Comment: You can use json data type like this

    days: json("days")
                .$type<string[]>()
                .default([])
                .notNull(),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in the following way:

I used the custom types of drizzle-orm,

```
import { customType } from 'drizzle-orm/mysql-core';
```

create a function 'customSet' which receives as a parameter the name that it will have in the table and the array of the elements that I want to use to form my set

the function returns the function the customType function of drizzle-orm
We can pass a configuration object as a parameter to the function,
In the configuration we can execute a function to transform the data before saving it in the database and after obtaining it.

dataType: we pass it a string that must be an SQL statement, in my case I tell it that I want to save a set of data in the SET(value1, value2, ...) format.

toDriver - A function that converts input values into a string that will be sent to the "driver" or data access layer. Here, it appears to simply concatenate the values with commas.

fromDriver - A function that converts data received from the "driver" back to a usable format.

This 'customType' function is called with the 'name' provided as an argument, this makes the field name the one provided in "name"

```
  function customSet(name: string, values: string[]) {
      return customType<{ data: string[]; driverData: string }>({
        dataType: () => `SET(${values.map((value) => `'${value}'`).join(',')})`,
    toDriver: (inputValues) => `${inputValues.join(',')}`,
    fromDriver: (driverValues: string) => driverValues.replace(/{|}/g, '').split(','),
  })(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. After googling I can tell, that there's no way to store an array in a MySQL database. Here's a topic: [How to store arrays in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371639/how-to-store-arrays-in-mysql)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can store a stringified json object as a string and parse the object into an array when fetching it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

there are two possible ways:

- usign `josn` and store data as an array
- using the `.array()` at the end of your column in schema definition

Comment: ... you mean JSON?