# For a MYSQL table which has a column containing an array, how do I select all the entries for which the column contains all the elements in a list?

Tags: mysql, select

So I have a MYSQL table, and one of the columns (call it TAGS) is an array which contains a list of tag names.  For example, a given entry could have a TAGS column value of "TAG A, TAG B, TAG C."

Now I want to select all the entries from the table which have a TAGS column value which contains all of the tag names in a given array.  For example, I might want to get all the entries for which TAGS contains TAG A, TAG B, and TAG C.

Right now I have it set up where it will return all the entries with a TAGS column value which contains the exact same array of tag names.  However, as the question states, I want to return all the entries with a TAGS column which only contains at least all the given tag names, the TAG column could contain additional tag names and it would still be returned.

Comment: That is a very bad design. It should either be a related field, enum/set field or JSON field. So you should normalize your table before continuing.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Maybe not ENUM but SET?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL query finding values in a comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033047/mysql-query-finding-values-in-a-comma-separated-string)

Comment: @MarkusZeller The answer you posted would work if I was just trying to find, for example, all entries for which column TAGS contains TAG A.  But I want to find all entries which contain multiple tags. I saw your other comment but I'm unfamiliar with related, set or JSON fields.

Comment: are they really separated by ", " not just a comma?

Comment: this is just `where concat(', ',TAGS,', ') like '%, TAG A, %' and concat(', ',TAGS,', ') like '%, TAG B, %'...`.  if it is just comma, not comma-space, then it is `where find_in_set('TAG A',TAGS) and find_in_set('TAG B',TAGS)...`

Comment: @ysth yes it is a comma and then a space

Comment: @wiredvision This would work for multiple tags, because you can use logical operators like AND / OR in WHERE clause. Just because it is a duplicate does not mean you can copy and paste, but in general it answers your question.

Comment: @ysth this line: "where find_in_set('TAG A',TAGS) and find_in_set('TAG B',TAGS)" seems to accomplish what I'm needing to do for now, however I understand for future reference this is improper design

Comment: it absolutely won't.  for instance, `find_in_set('TAG B', 'TAG A, TAG B')` will be false, because it sees in the list "TAG A" and " TAG B", not "TAG A" and "TAG B"

Comment: Right, stated another way, FIND_IN_SET() only works for comma-separated strings, not for comma-and-space-separated strings.

Comment: @ysth sorry I should have said that I changed the array of tags to be separated by only a comma, no space

Comment: @wiredvision: A comma separated string is something different than an array.... (see: [The reason that there are no arrays in SQL, is because most people don't really need it......](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371788/724039) )

Answer (score 1):

A better design would be to not store a comma separated string. (It does not matter if you call it an Array, or not)

It is always possible to generate a comma separated string afterward, using [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

When having a normalized table like (indexes left out, you (might) need to add them yourself!):

```
CREATE TABLE `NewTags` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `n` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

one can do:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag ORDER BY tag) as tags
FROM NewTags
WHERE tag='TAG A' or tag='TAG B' or tag='TAG C'
GROUP BY id
HAving count(*)=3
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/YWoCDA9M)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` function of MySQL.

Of course, you can use `LIKE`. But if your tags are comma-seperated and you want to ensure exact matches, it is better to select `FIND_IN_SET`. However, it requires that your tags do not contain comma themselves.

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('TAG A', TAGS) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('TAG B', TAGS) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('TAG C', TAGS) > 0;
```

If the value of tags column contains a space after comma, you need to remove that space using `REPLACE` function. Following query shows that.

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('TAG A', REPLACE(TAGS, ' ', '')) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('TAG B', REPLACE(TAGS, ' ', '')) > 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('TAG C', REPLACE(TAGS, ' ', '')) > 0;
```

In your programming languge, you can create dynamic query. This is Node.js code.

```js
const tags = ["TAG A", "TAG B", "TAG C"]  // Example array of tags
let sql = "SELECT * FROM TAGS WHERE "

const conditions = []
for (let tag of tags) {
    const condition = `FIND_IN_SET('${tag}', REPLACE(TAGS, ' ', '')) > 0`
    conditions.push(condition)
}
sql += conditions.join(" AND ") + ";"
```

You can check in [this link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php#:%7E:text=MySQL%20FIND_IN_SET()%20returns%20the,%2C%27%20(comma)%20character.) how to use `FIND_IN_SET` function.

Thank you.

Comment: better to just remove the extra space, with `REPLACE(TAGS, ', ', ',')`, not all spaces

Comment: Is the ">0" necessary? It seems to work without this

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WHERE find_in_set('TAG A',TAGS) and find_in_set('TAG B',TAGS)
```

As mentioned in comments by ysth, this line seems to accomplish what I'm needing to do for now, however I understand for future reference this is improper design