Add sql files in python library
I have a python library where I have sql files and I want users to be able to install the library via pip and have access to those files. I use poetry to build the library.
I tried the following but it doesn't work:
[tool.poetry.include]
# Include the SQL files in the package
include = [
    "my_library/queries/*.sql"
]

I'm getting the following error:
The Poetry configuration is invalid:
  - [include] {'include': ['my_library/queries/*.sql']} is not of type 'array'

I use poetry 1.6.1. How can I include the sql files in the library?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371639/how-to-store-arrays-in-mysql

If the files are in the same folder as your python files, poetry will include them in the package by default (unless they are listed in the .gitignore). So there should be no need for any config on your side.

@nicomp You pointed to a completely unrelated question. This question is about adding SQL files to a python distribution.
